# Why is the output of this code blank

Tags: c, string, bit-manipulation

I am trying to print the power set of a string.

The code gets compiled successfully, but, when executed, nothing gets printed on the screen.

I am unable to understand the reason behind this.

Below is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    char s[]="abcd";
    int i,j,k=1;
    int y=strlen(s);
    int z=pow(2,y);
    for(i=0;i<z;i++)
    {
        k=1;
        for(j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            if(j & k)
                printf(" %c",s[j]);
            k=k<<1;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should print the values of `j` and `k` before the `if(j&k)`, and I think you'll see the problem. Or learn to use a debugger, so you can step through the code and see what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`j & k` always evaluates to `0`.

```
j =  0, k =    1     ==> j & K = 0
j =  1, k =   10     ==> j & K = 0 
j = 10, k =  100     ==> j & K = 0
j = 11, k = 1000     ==> j & K = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wrong with my logic to put inside the code.Now it's fine

Answer (score 1):

This code works as you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char s[] = "abcd";
        int i,j;
        int y = strlen(s);
        int z = 1 << y;
        for(i = 0; i < z; i++)
        {
                for(j = 0; j < y; j++)
                {
                        if(i & 1 << j)
                                printf(" %c",s[j]);
                }
                putchar('\n');
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I admit that I've made extra changes in your code, which are irrelevant to your question.

What actually matters is `i & 1 << j`. This checks the `j`th bit of `i`. You can also write `i & (1 << j)` for the sake of readability.